# Handle client-side request timeout in java

Tags: java, servlets, request, timeout, httprequest

A client sends a request and catches a timeout exception. However the server is still processing the request and saving it to the database. Before that happening, the client already sent a second request which doubles the record on the database. How do I prevent that from happening? Im using java servlets and javascript.

Comment: Err, increase the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:-

1) Increase the client timeout.

2) Make the server more efficient so it can respond faster.

3) Get the server to respond with an intermediate "I'm working on it" response before returning with the main response.

4) Does the server need to do *all* the work before it responds to the client, or can some be offloaded to a seperate process for running later?

Answer (score 0):

> A client sends a request and catches a timeout exception. However the server is still processing the request

Make the servlet generate some output (can be just blank spaces) and flush the stream every so often (every 15 seconds for example).

If the connection has been closed on the client side, the write will fail with a  socket exception.

> Before that happening, the client already sent a second request which doubles the record on the database

Use the atomicity of the database, for example, a unique key. Start the process by creating a unique record (maybe in some "unfinished" status), it will fail if the record already exists.